# Псевдокласс :target

Tags: css

Возможно ли без использования скрипта с помощью псевдокласса :target осуществить следующее:
На странице имеются 2 блока и 2 ссылки на них соответственно, один из блоков изначально скрыт свойством display:none.  при нажатии ссылки в url  с его id его значение display становиться block, а другого none и наоборот.
Например такой код не работает:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background:#00BFFF
}
#block2 {
  display: none;
}
#block2:target {
  display: block;
}
#block2:target #block1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#block1"> первый блок</a>
<br>
<a href="#block2"> втрой блок</a>
<div id="block1">первый блок</div>
<div id="block2">втрой блок</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо использовать конструкции `:target` и `:not(:target)`

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  $('#block1').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00BFFF
}
.visible,
div:target {
  display: block;
}
div:not(:target):not(.visible) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#block1"> линк на первый блок</a>
<br>
<a href="#block2"> линк на второй блок</a>
<div id="block1" class="visible">первый блок</div>
<div id="block2">втрой блок</div>
```

Comment: Первый блок должен отображаться изначально и срываться только при таргете на второй блок. Или же это не возможно средствами css?

Comment: тогда без JS не обойтись. Псевдо классы фактически "не существуют". Потому они и "псевдо"... так что надо отдельный класс, и при первом нажатии удалять его (ну или inline css - как Вам удобней). Я обновил ответ

Comment: Печально что без js не обойтись.... но это все что я хотел узнать... Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант из [ответа на похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354472/2881286), без яваскрипта, но со своими ограничениями, в частности на порядок вкладок.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00BFFF
}
.tab, .tab:target ~ #block1  {
  display: none;
}
#block1, .tab:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#block1"> линк на первый блок</a>
<br>
<a href="#block2"> линк на второй блок</a>
<div id="block2" class="tab">втрой блок</div>
<div id="block1" class="tab">первый блок</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Поставь блокам абсолют позишин - все.....

Comment: Абсолютное позиционирование не решает проблему. Высота первого и второго блока могут быть разными, поэтому и нужно скрывать тот, что сейчас неактивен.